# Apache2 breaks after creating symlink in his subfolders

Tags: apache2, symlink

After installing apache2 im trying to create symlink from folder site-available to site-enabled. After it had been done apache2 just stops working. While trying to reload it it says "job for apache2.service failed".  systemtlc in photos. What am I doing wrong?

Commend for symlink im using:
ln -s ../sites-available/010-dev.conf 010-dev.conf

I should also add that after creating the symlink, removing it doesnt fix apache. Even apache default site is still not loading, I have to reinstall apache.

[systemtlc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yy5Ut.png)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the apache's error log file (usually it is located under `/var/log/httpd/error.log` or `/var/log/apache/error.log` or something like that). It will have more info about the error.

Comment: There is no apache or httpd folder

Comment: maybe /var/log/apache2

Comment: There should be something like that

Comment: Yes! This is the file I'm talking about. But I don't see any error. Just look at it after apache fails to start.

Comment: OK. now look at the error log. There should something there explaining why it doesn't work.